# On aws personalize, users and items datasets requires 1 metadata field, why? is it necessary?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I am trying to create a recommendation system.
I would like to recommend users to subscribe to topics based on topics they already have subscribed to.
As mentioned in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/how-it-works-dataset-schema.html), there is a requirement of 1 metadata field for the users and items (topics in my case) schemas.
I couldn't find any worthy field to put there.

Why is it a requirement? What should I do then? How impactful is it on the final recommendations score if I leave it blank? Am I missing any other way to solve that issue? Do you think that aws personalize is a good fit for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is not mandatory to create all three dataset types. I found it out from [aws-personalize-samles](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-personalize-samples/tree/master/core_use_cases/user_personalization). Couldn't figure it out from the docs.
I thought of deleting this question, because it might be a too much of a noob question (seems like it from the downvoting), but heck, if it may shorten someone else time to figure it out by finding the samples, I will leave it as is.

Sorry if I annoyed some people!